# Why does can't shmat() access my shared memory segment? (ERRNO 13)

Tags: c, unix, posix, ipc, shared-memory

For a UNIX/C project, I'm supposed to allocate two shared memory segments (which child processes will eventually access with read-only and write permissions, respectively) of two integers each.  But any time I try to call shmat(3), it ends up returning -1, setting errno to EACCES, apparently indicating insufficient permissions.  I've produced what seems to be the minimum required code fro the error below, with possibly a couple extra includes:

```
#define _SVID_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i, j, shmid, tshmid;
    int * clock;
    int * shmMsg;
    tshmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int)*2, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0777); //0777 permissions are more liberal than I need, but I've tried other various literals and numbers as well as just CREAT/EXCL.
    if (tshmid < 1){
        printf("Error: In parent process (%d), shmid came up %d \n",getpid(),shmid);
        exit(-1);
    }
    clock = (int *) shmat(shmid,NULL,0); //I've also tried this with the second argument as (void *) 0, and with the third argument as "(SHM_R | SHM_W)" and "0777"
    if (clock == (void *) -1){
        printf("Error: First shmat couldn't shmattach to shmid #%d. ERRNO %d\n",shmid,errno);
        shmdt(clock);
        exit(-1);
    } //it never even gets this far
    shmdt(clock);
}
```

Each time, this produces an error message like:

> Error: First shmat couldn't shmattach to shmid #1033469981. ERRNO 13

The longer version of my program initially returned an identical error, but errno was set to 43 (EIDRM: Segment identified by shm_id was removed).  I've recursively chmodded the whole directory to full access, so that's not the issue, and every time my program crashes I have to manually deallocate the shared memory using ipcrm, so the shmids apply to actual segments.  Why won't it attach?

Comment: As for the need to `ipcrm`, you probably should have your program use `shmctl()` to remove the segment if an error occurs before successfully attaching it.  After attaching it, you can uncdonditionally remove it so that you don't have to keep track of where and when to do that; it remains usable as long as at least one process has it attached.

Comment: But as for the error, you record the memory segment ID in variable `tshmid`, but try to attach the one identified by uninitialized variable `shmid`.  After I fix that, your program runs for me without error.